# USB Mouse Passthrough

Tags: usb, arduino-leonardo

I am currently doing research for a project of mine. My goal is simple: I want to pass input from a physical mouse, to a microcomputer to process the input and modify, and send the input in the form of USB HID to a PC.

> Mouse ---> Microcomputer (input modified) ---> PC

The Microcomputer preferably should be able to both send data to the PC (in the form of USB HID inputs as a mouse) and receive data from the PC.

I found the arduino Leonardo can act as a USB slave and emulate mouse movement, half of what I want. I need some microcomputer with capabilities to act both as a USB host and as a USB slave. I don't have experience with microcomputers, and I don't know how to find something with this feature.

Comment: Do you want to be able to change settings in the mouse from the computer? Can you explain what you want to modify? The mouse speed? Could it be possible to do this on the computer with a special driver? Which operating system?

Comment: I want the middleman computer to be able to modify the input to the main PC based on data from the main PC. A simple file pipe or something like that is enough for what I need. I assume it's possible with a USB controller in slave mode, because I've seen software based RGB keyboard controls, etc. However, in this case I don't need to access the mouse.

Comment: What do you want to modify? The mouse speed? Buttons? Auto-repeat?

Comment: I want to move a physical mouse, modify the movement in my microcomputer (e.g. multiply coordinates by two), then send it to the PC (the microcomputer will act as a virtual HID).

Comment: I'm not sure if that will work. A mouse does not know coordinates. If it is possible then it can be done on a linux computer as well without Arduino. I agree with the answer by @gdsports , attach a usb host shield.

Comment: Even in an incremental mode, the increments reported could be multiplied.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The cleanest solution to this problem would be to use an MCU with dual USB interfaces, one capable of being a USB host.   There are a few such parts in the STM32F4 lineup, and likely other brands as well, but not immediately clear if there are any with existing Arduino support.  Hardware wise, I believe you can do it with an inexpensive STM32F446 "Nucleo" board, though the pins of the USB interface are only available on headers, which you would need to wire to USB connectors.

A USB host shield is a possibility, but it's a bit "tacky" as a solution since it involves hanging a fairly sophisticated controller off a more primitive MCU, making an "upside down" architecture, and more expensive than an all-in-one solution, but it could be where you'll find the most existing code to support your effort.

One of the simplest things you could actually do would be to use a ps/2 mouse instead of a USB one, and interface that by bit-banging its simple serial interface.  Then you could use a board like a Leonardo or one of the Teensy series which has a customizable USB device interface, to present to the host computer as a USB mouse.

Comment: I was thinking about using a pi as USB host, then passing coordinates over GPIO to an arduino slave. But I feel like there will be input delay.

Comment: I like the nucleo as an option, I'm just worried that it may be too complex for me to understand, and I don't think I have the proper tools to solder on a header for usb (I have never purchased a small computer like this before).

Comment: It will indeed be challenging integrating the firmware - while a lot more capable, the examples also are far less turn-key than Arduino code.   In terms of attaching a USB port, what I did was to get a cheap USB extension cable, cut it in half, and crimp female header pins to it to plug into the board expansion headers (though watch out, the color code in cheap USB cables is usually completely wrong!).  These are all skills worth learning, but each takes time.  If this is the first time, you probably want to go with the host shield or the ps/2 mouse where you can stay purely Arduino.

Comment: thanks for the heads up. I found a nice little board while browsing adafruit, the Trinket M0 that i fcan couple with a USB host controller. https://github.com/gdsports/usb-metamorph/blob/master/README.md I found this github repo that has a lot of info about USB and stuff. I'm not even sure what the repo is about, I just skimmed over it, but the trinket m0 with USB host shield looks promising.

Comment: Hmm, while that combination might work, I worry that could bring the risk of the worst of both worlds; the atypical,only quasi-Arduino M0 platform, and the indirectness of the host shield.

Comment: The nucleo seems like my best bet. How do I research this further? What should I look for to determine if the computer has the functionality to work as a device and a host? It's not clear to me what I'm looking for in datasheets, etc. Thank you.

Comment: The hardware has the functionality, the issue is more that you'll need to do a lot of non-trivial software work, best case would be having to smoosh together two full example projects, figure out the semantics of handoff between them, wrangle a compiler more directly, etc.  Definitely worth the effort if making a product, less clear for a one-off and likely not if unfamiliar with such tasks. 
 Whatever you choose, start by getting each of hosting the mouse and emulating a mouse working independently.

Comment: Okay, thanks. It seems like I will need to actually order the device and tinker with it for a bit. I'm just wondering in general how I can tell which computer has what USB functionality. How did you figure out that Nucleo has this functionality? Was it through the SoC datasheet or something else? I'll probably be ordering a leonardo or something with the same SoC, just to get started with device emulation (i.e. slave device acting as USB HID).

Comment: So I found this: http://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers/stm32f446.html?querycriteria=productId=LN1875 We can see that there are two entries under USB, "USB OTG FS and USB OTG FS/HS", so I guess that says that there are two usb controllers capable of operating in OTG mode. Is this correct?

Comment: I know that I have already asked a lot, but how would i differentiate between USB ports and a USB controller? If I understand it is true that one host can have many ports, and multiple ports don't necessarily mean multiple controllers.

Comment: I hadn't recalled both being host capable, but that may be the case.  A given USB function can only support one connection, multiplexing is only possible by inserting hubs, which is not a complication you'd likely want here.

Answer (score 2):

Plug a USB Host Shield into the Leonardo.

```
USB mouse --- USB Host Shield --- Leonardo --- PC
```

[USB Host Shield Library](https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0)

[Circuits@Home Project](https://www.circuitsathome.com/arduino_usb_host_shield_projects/)

```
/*
 * USB Mouse pass through. Works at HID report level. HID report is not decoded.
 * Tested on Leonardo with Arduino USB host shield, IDE 1.8.5, and Logitech Marble
 * trackball/mouse. This is a proof of concept so is not guaranteed to work with 
 * all USB mice/trackballs.
 */
// USB host mouse from USB Host Shield Library. Install using Library Manager
#include <hidboot.h>

// USB device mouse library included with Arduino IDE 1.8.5
#include <Mouse.h>

// Satisfy the IDE, which needs to see the include statment in the ino too.
#ifdef dobogusinclude
#include <spi4teensy3.h>
#endif
#include <SPI.h>

class MouseRptParser : public MouseReportParser
{
protected:
    void Parse(USBHID *hid, bool is_rpt_id, uint8_t len, uint8_t *buf);
};

void MouseRptParser::Parse(USBHID *hid, bool is_rpt_id, uint8_t len, uint8_t *buf)
{
  Serial.print("MouseRptParser::Parse");
  // Show USB HID mouse report
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < len ; i++) {
    Serial.print(' '); Serial.print(buf[i], HEX);
  }
  Serial.println();

  // On error - return
  if (buf[2] == 1)
    return;

  if (len > 2) {
    uint8_t mouseRpt[4];
    mouseRpt[0] = buf[0];
    mouseRpt[1] = buf[1];
    mouseRpt[2] = buf[2];
    mouseRpt[3] = 0;
    HID().SendReport(1,mouseRpt,sizeof(mouseRpt));
  }
}

USB     Usb;
HIDBoot<USB_HID_PROTOCOL_MOUSE>    HidMouse(&Usb);

MouseRptParser Prs;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin( 115200 );
#if !defined(__MIPSEL__)
  while (!Serial) delay(1); // Wait for serial port to connect - used on Leonardo, Teensy and other boards with built-in USB CDC serial connection
#endif
  Serial.println("Start");

  if (Usb.Init() == -1) {
    Serial.println("USB host shield did not start.");
  }
  delay( 200 );

  HidMouse.SetReportParser(0, &Prs);

  Mouse.begin();
}

void loop()
{
  Usb.Task();
}
```